# Datepicker vue3 put the date in the correct format

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3

I am using for the date "datepicker", I cannot get it back in the correct format. I have tried several different ways with the documentation, but still cannot. Thank you for help.
this is how I get the date : Sat Jun 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <datepicker v-model="date"  lang="fr" :locale="date-fns/locale/fr"  type="date" :format="dd-MM-YYYY" :lowerLimit="Date.now()"></datepicker>
                                        
    </div>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
import Datepicker from 'vue3-datepicker'
import { ref } from 'vue'
//import { add } from 'date-fns'
const date = ref(new Date())
const dateFrom = ref(new Date())

export default {
    name:'RechercheDate',
    components: { 
        Datepicker
    },
    data(){
        return{
          date:""
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: please give the link to the component docs

Comment: Yes :) https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker/#props-and-attributes

Comment: Try out `inputFormat="dd-MM-YYYY"` instead of `:format="dd-MM-YYYY"`

Comment: I get this error : Format string contains an unescaped latin alphabet character `Y`

Comment: did you remove `:`?

Comment: I did like this : <datepicker v-model="date"  lang="fr"  type="date" :locale="date-fns/locale/fr"  :inputFormat="dd-MM-YYYY" :lowerLimit="Date.now()"></datepicker>

Comment: You should remove the : before locale and inputFormat

Comment: It works, I get as I did the date. I think I wrote my request incorrectly. The problem is that I get the date in this format: Sat Jun 12 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale)

Comment: could the problem be the way I upload to the localStorage ?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you did some small mistakes here:

Here is what your code somehow should look alike:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <datepicker v-model="date" lang="fr" locale="date-fns/locale/fr" 
 format="dd-MM-YYYY" type="date" :lowerLimit="new Date()"></datepicker>
                                        
    </div>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
import Datepicker from 'vue3-datepicker'
import { ref } from 'vue'

export default {
    name:'RechercheDate',
    components: { 
        Datepicker
    },
    setup() {
      const date = ref(new Date());
 
      return {
         date,
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

What did I change?

I put the date `ref` into an Setup function and return it, thus you do not need the `data` attribute anymore. you did initalize a dateFormat, but didn't use it, If you want to you need to change `format` to `:format="dateFormat"` and add dateFormat to your setup Function (probably no ref because it won't change) and return it too.

Also. the `:` infront of attributes are only needed if you want to execute Javascript in it (or use variables)

Update: After checking for the doc I also need to confirm what Boussadjra Brahim already said, the format Property is called `inputFormat`

Comment: Thank you for all these explanations, I get the date like this : Sam 12 juin 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (heure d'été d'Europe centrale)